# Best way to clean, adapt and validate data

Tags: python, validation

I'm wondering what the best approach is to handling incoming data that includes units along with the values. 
The incoming data has a label and a value. The label indicates what type of data it is and the value contains both the value and the unit. So for instance I have a field with label 'elevation' and value '120 m' or value '363 ft'. Basically I need to do four things:

1. check the unit to see if I need to convert to 'base unit' (if it includes ft, calculate it meters)
2. clean the value to strip the unit (remove ' m' and possibly thousands separator and change decimal character (point vs comma) )
3. validate the data (right now I check to see if value is '-' as this should be 0, but more validation should be done)
4. check whether to include the field or not. (if the field is present as column in the database)

How I'm handling it now (not efficient/clear!) is Using the KeyError as the fields are not mandatory so could not exist.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'elevation': ['1.200 m']})
try:
    if ' m' in df['elevation'].values[0]:
        df['elevation'] = df['elevation'].values[0].replace(' m', '').replace('.', '')
        if df['elevation'].values[0] == '-':
            df['elevation'] = int(df['elevation'].values[0].replace('-', '0'))
    elif ' ft' in df['elevation'].values[0]:
        df['elevation'] = df['elevation'].values[0].replace(' ft', '')
        if df['elevation'].values[0] == '-':
           df['elevation'] = int(df['elevation'].values[0].replace('-', '0'))
        df['elevation'] = round(float(df['elevation'].values[0]) * 0.3048, 2)

except KeyError:
    pass

print(df)
```

The check if the field needs to be included is done by retrieving the columns from the table and check if the dataframe columns are in that list:

```
# retrieve column map
query = """SELECT * from information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'table' """
try:
    df_columns = pd.read_sql(query, con=engine)
    columns = df_columns['column_name']
except Exception as e:
    print('query failed', e)
dropped_columns=[]
for i in df.columns:
    if columns.isin([i]).any():
         pass
    else:
       df.drop(i, 1, inplace=True)
       print("column dropped:", i)
       dropped_columns.append(i)
df_dropped = pd.DataFrame({'dropped_column': dropped_columns})
```

Few things that are nasty here; checking on the unit for every field seems inefficient. However, if I generalize this check I could end up with false matches (' m/s' for some velocity field) and different fields will have different 'normal values' to validate on.

I need to do this for many different fields so I'm looking at an efficient way of handling this. I know there are modules like Cerberus and valideer available that might help out here, but curious to see how others are handling this. 
Would you make a data mapping of all possible fields with the expected values, units,  conversions and normal values and check and adapt based on this?

Comment: Can you have multiple rows of data at a time? Something like `pd.DataFrame({'elevation': ['1.200 m', '6 ft', '100 ft']})`

Comment: @SreeramTP no. I'm basically getting two arrays; 1 for labels and one for values. I then combine those into a dataframe, drop duplicates and transpose to do all kinds of operations on it more easily

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want to use the `unit-converter` library (available with `pip install`)!

Edit: OP is investigating *Pint*, which seemed to offer some extra customization.

From their documentation (https://pypi.org/project/unit-converter/):

```
>>> from unit_converter.converter import convert, converts
>>>
>>> convert('2.78 daN*mm^2', 'mN*µm^2')
>>> Decimal('2.78E+10')
>>>
>>> converts('2.78 daN*mm^2', 'mN*µm^2')
>>> '2.78E+10'
>>>
>>> converts('78 min', 'h')
>>> '1.3'
>>>
>>> converts('52°C', '°F')
>>> '125.6'
```

For your use case you would just use an `.apply(lambda v: convert(v, base))`, with a `base` given by the needs of your column.

If the columns and bases are all known, you could even do the apply over the rows instead

```
def make_conversions(spec):
    def conversions(row):
        for col, base in spec.items():
            row[col] = convert(row[col], base)
    return conversions

spec = {'elevation': 'm'}
conversions = make_conversions(spec)
df.apply(conversions, axis=1)
```

Comment: thanks. this is very useful indeed, will give this a try!

I can add to the spec definition I guess to set 'normal' values (min max?) to also validate

Comment: what is 'row' in this case? row[col] gives me an error "TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer" and row seems to be shaped as my df being transposed.

Comment: I got it.. it's the unit-converter not throwing the right exceptions in case I try to 'convert' percentages (strip the from the string %). 
I'll work that in the function. 

Still wondering though why a nested function instead of passing through the df as second argument to a function along with spec ?

Comment: Just for convenience (and "safety", sort of), since in theory you are using the same partial function many times for all your rows.

Comment: unit-converter is helpful, but needs quite some adjustments I'm afraid.. it's not working if there is no number (' m') or negative number. also is missing quite some units I need. But will see how I can either extend it directly or expend functions around it

Comment: Ah, that's a pity.  I'm not surprised it refuses to parse values without a number, but the negative is strange.  You can obviously special case those two, but sorry for any complications =/

Comment: no problem! I've shifted to using Pint, which seems easier to work with and expand with own units. I'll update once I've completed it all